# Adding vector icon font to website header name?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, vector

I want to design my website header using vector swirls, i have added @font-face with required font files.

Here is my header.php code and i want to use vector swirls on top and bottom of site-branding class

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <span class="site-branding-design"></span>
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <span class="site-branding-design"></span>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'minima-royale' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="screen-reader-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'minima-royale' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'minima-royale' ); ?></a></div>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

**CSS Code:-**

```
.site-branding-design{
    font-family: 'Conv_Nymphette';
    font-size: 16px;
    content: "a";
}
```

Character Map of Font
http://www.fontspace.com/nymphont/nymphette/11741.charmap

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.site-branding-design{
  position:absolute;
  font-family: Conv_Nymphette;
  top:0;
  left:-5px;
  content: "\25AE";
}
```

"\25AE"  is your font "character". You can also use UTF-8 character codes.

Comment: no, it didn't work. I want to use design of character 'a' as shown in character map.

Comment: Did you try content: "a"; ?
UTF-8 lower case is 61, Uppercase is 41. And play with the positioning too.